# Changes to dependency not getting picked up by npm install

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-install

Here is the setup:

- `project-A` (main project) package.json points to `git+ssh://git@github.com/.../library-B#branch1` as devDependency
- `library-B#branch1` package.json points to `https://github.com/.../library-C/tarball/branch2` as devDependency
- I made changes to `library-C` and merged them into `library-C#branch2` (I also did a version bump in `library-C` but not `library-B`), I checked that tarball url linked to by previous bullet does fetch correct version with my changes
- I went back to `project-A` and ran `npm install`, changes were not picked up

Should `project-A` automatically check for these changes with `npm install` or is the check shallow (one level deep)? What's the best way to address this so `npm install` is able to detect changes to sub-dependency automatically? Should I version-bump B? Should I avoid branches as dependencies altogether?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow--you made changes to C, but didn't update B to reflect the update? You'd need to update C in B so the lock file is updated.

Comment: Correct, I was confused about how package-lock gets used. In my case `library-B` gets pulled in by A so it doesn't have its own package-lock, but updating one in A fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I didn't understand how package-lock worked. I assumed that `npm install` would fetch a checksum message for each dependency listed in package-lock and check if it changed.

Instead, it looks like it checks package-lock checksum against one it computes for each locally fetched dependency. Updating the checksum (`integrity`) in `project-A` package-lock for `library-C` dependency caused the correct version to get fetched (you can also achieve the same by force-reinstalling, which will update package-lock).